# Evaluate $a_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(4k-1)^p}{n^{p+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $a_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(4k-1)^p}{n^{p+1}}$ using Stolz-Cesaro theorem .

Now, this is my approach( i don' know if it is correct) : $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{3^p+5^p+\dots+(4n-1)^p+(4n)^p-3^p-5^p-\dots-(4n-1)^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}$

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(4n)^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}$
$=\sim \frac 1 n \cdot \frac {4^p} {\frac{p+1}{n}}$ 
$a_n=\frac{4^p}{p+1}$( at the very end i approximated infinitesimally, also p is a general case,it doesn't say anything about it in my book ). Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{K=0}^{n} \frac{(4k-1)^
p}{n^{p+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{4k}{n}-\frac{1}{n} \right)^p$$ As $n \to \infty$, we change the summation to integration by taking  $k/n=x$ and neglecting $1/n$  inside parentheses and get
$$L=\int_{0}^{1} (4x)^p dx=\frac{4^{p}}{p+1}.$$